# Is there a way to animate to the next or previous -ms-scroll-snap-points-x?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm using webview in a xaml app, and I'm using snap points for panning through a list of objects.  Is it possible to tell the element to scroll to the next/previous snap point?

I'm currently using jquery and just animating the scrollLeft property.  But it isn't nearly as smooth as when panning with touch.  So I'm looking for a more native solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible with IE11, but not support in IE10.  Using msZoomTo, which zooms and/or pans with animation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254949(v=vs.85).aspx